# Change value in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

from my api I get the following array:

```
const apiResponse = [
        {
          "accountBillNumber": "123456789",
          "amountMoney": "0.00"
        },
        {
          "accountBillNumber": "987654321",
          "amountMoney": "0.01"
        },
    ];
```

I would like to write a very short code that will always change the `value` from `accountBillNumber` to `value.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 ')`. Can it be done in a modern way with one line using es6 +?

Comment: Do you want to change the key `accoutnBillNumber` or its value?

Comment: _"with one line using es6 +?"_ - Why always those _"one line"_ requirements? Write maintainable code that you understand by just looking at it. If you need it to be as small as possible then use a minifier.

Comment: @Sid value. I would like change every accountBillNumber (1234567890, 9876543210) to (01 2345 6789, 98 7654 3210) using regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

```js
const apiResponse = [
  {
    "accountBillNumber": "123456789",
    "amountMoney": "0.00"
  },
  {
    "accountBillNumber": "987654321",
    "amountMoney": "0.01"
  },
];

apiResponse.forEach(x => x.accountBillNumber = x.accountBillNumber.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 '));

console.log(apiResponse);
```

Or the [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to create a new array, as @Mamun's answer suggests.

```js
const apiResponse = [
    {
      "accountBillNumber": "123456789",
      "amountMoney": "0.00"
    },
    {
      "accountBillNumber": "987654321",
      "amountMoney": "0.01"
    },
];

const result = apiResponse.map(x => {
  const { accountBillNumber, ...rest } = x;

  return {
    accountBillNumber: accountBillNumber.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 '),
    ...rest
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You removed "amountMoney". I would like to save object, but only value in accountBillNumber I want to formatted using regex.

Comment: you could also destrucuture the object `apiResponse.forEach(({ accountBillNumber: bill }) => bill = bill.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 '));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const apiResponse = [
    {
      "accountBillNumber": "123456789",
      "amountMoney": "0.00"
    },
    {
      "accountBillNumber": "987654321",
      "amountMoney": "0.01"
    },
];
var res = apiResponse.map(v => { 
  return {
    amountMoney: v.amountMoney, 
    accountBillNumber: v.accountBillNumber.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1 ')
  };
});
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) here. I included it in my answer. Because the APIs response could always change. And you wouldn't want to hard code all the objects properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
apiResponse.map(x=>({...x,accountBillNumber:x.accountBillNumber.replace(/(^\d{2}|\d{4})+?/g, '$1')}))
```

Try this